# php fopen COM port need only one time for Arduino

Tags: php, ajax, arduino-uno

Here are my code in index.php

```
<input type="text" id="press">
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready( function ($) {
        $('#press').keypress(function(e){
            if(e.keyCode==13){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'run.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'text',
                    data: {
                        action: 'ok'
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here is run.php

```
$action = $_POST['action'];
if($action == 'ok'){
    $port = fopen("com3", "w");
    sleep(2);
    fwrite($port,'n');
    fclose($port);
}
```

The problem is: I don't want to run

> $port = fopen("com3", "w");

any time I call the ajax function because I will have to wait at least 2 seconds to Arduino restart. Is there any way to run fopen only one time and when I call ajax function it just run fwrite?